# want to know where OPAM package installed while using win10 bash

Tags: bash, windows-10, visual-studio-code, ocaml, opam

I'm trying to setup development environment for OCaml in Windows 10.
I installed OCaml & OPAM in bash for win10. Then I installed several packages(merlin, ocp-indent etc.) that i need.

My final goal is to integrate OCaml with VScode, using vscode-ocaml extension.(https://github.com/hackwaly/vscode-ocaml) To finish setup, i have to add path of OCaml REPL, OPAM, merlin and OCP -
 indent. But I can't find where OCaml package installed in windows file system.

So, Does anybody knows where Ocaml, OPAM and OCaml package installed when using win 10 bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to do this using the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) as of today.

## Using VScode for Windows

Let me remind you that WSL isn't a simple shell emulator. It runs native Linux binaries (more about this [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/04/22/windows-subsystem-for-linux-overview/)) and thus, I don't think you can have a Windows instance of VScode work with a Linux instance of OCaml.

## Using VScode for Linux

On the other hand, you won't be able to run Linux VScode from WSL since GUI application aren't supported yet. However, a quick Google search revealed [this article](https://www.howtogeek.com/261575/how-to-run-graphical-linux-desktop-applications-from-windows-10s-bash-shell/) which suggests it might work using 64-bit GUI applications. But once again, it's not officially supported by Microsoft.

## Alternatives

There is still hope, however. One thing you can do is installing [OCaml for Windows](https://fdopen.github.io/opam-repository-mingw/installation/), which will provide you with Windows binaries for the OCaml/OPAM toolchain that you will be able to integrate with VScode for Windows.

Or, but this is pure speculation, set up a non-graphical editor (such as vim or emacs) for the time beaing and wait for Microsoft to support GUI applications in WSL, because I think this coming soon. But once again, pure speculation.

---

**EDIT**: After some more research, [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/install_guide#for-anniversary-update-and-creators-update-install-using-lxrun) seems to indicate that WSL file system is installed under

```
%localappdata%\lxss\
```

However, the following warning immediately follows:

> Avoid creating and/or modifying files in `%localappdata%\lxss\` using Windows tools and apps! If you do, it is likely that your Linux files will be corrupted and data loss may occur. Avoid this issue by using a directory located under `/mnt/`.
>
> Read this [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/) for more information.

Comment: Thank you so much. It helped me a lot. I decided to try to be familiar with non GUI editor.

Answer (score 0):

Try using one of these:

```
locate opam
which opam
whereis opam
find / -name '*opam*'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, these will locate OPAM in the Linux filesystem, not the Windows one.